# Changing files while deploying in web role

Tags: azure

I have recently started working on `Windows Azure` and have a Web Role project in which I have to update one of the config entry in legacy code dependent file while starting up the WebRole in Azure. I would like to access files on the website in `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()` event and update the files in question before website starts.

The file is present in one of the folders within the `WebRole` project. My service definition files has default entries:

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

So the project code is present both in AppRoot (content is here) and sitesroot on deployment machine...

Environment variables - `RoleRoot, RdRoleRoot` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` seems to give folder locations...so I am not sure which one to use to update my file and at what location(`approot` or `sitesroot`) so my running application accesses correct file.

Any pointers on how to do it and which file to update will be really appreciated.

Comment: Is it necessary to have to change the file, post-deploy.  (i.e. is it some variable that you only know at run-time?)

If you know the value that needs to be updated pre-deploy, could you add a SlowCheetah transform to the file to modify it during the build, based on the target environment you are deploying to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder you need to change is the sitesroot folder as this is where IIS is configured to run your website from.  There is not a really clean way to query for where the sitesroot folder is, so your best bet is something like:

`sitesroot = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot") + @"\", @"sitesroot\0")`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need recently. Have a look at this blog article on how to modify the web.config OnStart
http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/05/13/azure-howto-programmatically-modify-web-config-on-webrole-startup/
To me, this is a little cleaner than looking for some environmental variables. Another thing to remember is that you need to run your role in an elevated context to modify the files. In your CSDEF, add 
    `<Runtime executionContext="elevated"/>` 
just under the WebRole XML tag.